# used spring initializr in intellij and I cannot run the demo application

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

So I used these settings to generate my spring file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLXxg.png)

Then I extracted that zip file and went into intellij and opened the new project.

The issue now is the src folder seems open although it shouldn't and if I navigate through to the DemoApplication.java I cannot run it.

This is how it looks like.

Really think it comes down to certain dependencies or so. I use java version 14 in intellij I think.

I watched lots of tutorials already and it seems simple but doesn't work for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kutqx.png)

I tried adding a module or changing the java version but both didn't seem to work

Comment: Hi there, you said you are using Java 14? But your spring application you've chosen Java 11! Is there any specific reason to use Java oldest versions? Why don't you use Java 17 or 20 in both IntelliJ IDEA and Spring Application. Try to update the Java version and make it same in both IDE and Spring.

Comment: As an addition you can simply create any Spring application in IntelliJ IDEA as well, there is no need to unzip.

Answer (score 0):

The "group" and "package name" starting with a "." seem wrong. Could you try again with other values?